# js object returns undefined even though property is there

Tags: javascript, class, object, undefined

I check for a property on an object but it returns undefined even though it is there. I assume I am testing in the wrong way?

I run this

```
console.log(self.modules[moduleId]);
```

and it outputs this:

```
Object

    composed: Array[2]

    prototypes: Array[2]

    slideshow: Slideshow

        cardFront: false

        currentSlide: 2
```

(So "slideshow" is an object, an instance of my class "Slideshow".)

I step in one step further to do this:

```
console.log(self.modules[moduleId].slideshow);
```

And it returns undefined.

My if-statement looks like this, although above is probably enough to get my issue.

```
if ( typeof( self.modules[moduleId].slideshow == 'undefined' ) ) {
```

Comment: Can you post a jsfiddle of your code?

Comment: For your debugging... To test for undefined you don't need typeof ... just this:

if ( self.modules[moduleId].slideshow == undefined ) { ... }

Comment: If `self.modules[moduleId]` really is the object structure you quote, then obviously `self.modules[moduleId].slideshow` **isn't** `undefined`. So something's got lost in the formation of the question.

Comment: @digitalextremist that is incorrect - in your case, 'undefined' should not be quoted.

Comment: It's clearly undefined, so you either have a typo somewhere or the object doesn't look like you think it does, and none of those can be solved by just looking at the posted code ?

Comment: YOur brackets are wrong. `if(typeof self.modules[moduleId].slideshow == 'undefined')` would be correct (or `if((typeof self.modules[moduleId].slideshow) == 'undefined')`, but those are unnecessary). ANd, another thing: keep in midn that this only checks `.slideshow`. If `modules[moduleId]` doesn't exist in the first palce, you still get an error - so check that one first.

Comment: @JohannesH Yes the expression would be less ambiguous written `typeof ( self.modules[moduleId].slideshow == 'undefined' )` the parenthesis is then just an expression, not a parameter of `typeof` which is a keyword not a native function.

Comment: @aduch: It's not that the `()` create "ambiguity," it's that they make the expression wrong. `==` will always return a boolean. `typeof` will always be `"boolean"` with the `()` as in the OP's question, because the `()` make `typeof` apply to the *expression* rather than to `self.modules[moduleId]`.

Comment: @aduch It still operates on the return value that way (which is tpye boolean). check yourself: `typeof (1 == 2)` returns `boolean`

Comment: Oh, and BTW: javascript offers the `in`operator to test the existence of object properties, which is nicer than the typeof operator in that case.

`if ('slideshow' in self.modules[moduleId])`

Comment: @T.J.Crowder you are right, I did not see that, my bad

Comment: @JohannesH.: `in` vs. `typeof ... === "undefined"` is totally a case-by-case thing. :-)

Comment: @JohannesH. - Good eye, maybe you should add it as an answer, as that seems to be the issue.

Comment: glad I could help. I'll add it as an answer for you to accept.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parantheses in your if-clause are wrong. With the parentheses you have, `typeof` operates on the value of the comparison expression, which is always a `boolean`.

Instead, use either

```
if (typeof self.modules[moduleId].slideshow == 'undefined')
```

...which will be true if `slideshow` doesn't exist at all on the object, or if it exists but has the value `undefined`.

Or make use of the `in`operator

```
if ('slideshow' in self.modules[moduleId])
```

...which will be true if the object or its prototype has the property, regardless of its value.

Or use `hasOwnProperty`:

```
if (self.modules[moduleId].hasOwnProperty('slideshow'))
```

...which will be true if the object itself (not its prototype) has the property, regardless of its value.

Comment: Nice additions, @T.J.Crowder, appreciate it!